# Full Text Search - Is there a way to get the column name that caused the row to be queried

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

In ms sql 2012 server, I have a Full Text Search index over a few columns.
I query using FREETEXTTABLE or CONTAINSTABLE  and My reaction should be different if the search text appeared on several columns than on the others.
Is there a way to distinguish or receive the column name that the result appeard in?
Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Can you provide a simple logic of how you change result dependant on the columns hit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're calling FREETEXTTABLE/CONTAINSTABLE with the `*` option to search across all columns. Instead, try making multiple calls, one for each column. You can do this in 1 query or as separate queries depending on the situation.

For example (the 1-query method):

```
SELECT
   Case
      When (MatchesColumn1or2.[KEY] is not null) Then 'Matches Column 1 or 2'
      When (MatchesColumn3.[KEY] is not null) Then 'Matches Column 3'
   End
FROM
   FREETEXTTABLE(MyTable, (Column1, Column2), 'cat AND dog') as MatchesColumn1or2
full outer join
   FREETEXTTABLE(MyTable, Column3, 'cat AND dog') as MatchesColumn3
   on (MatchesColumn1or2.[KEY] = MatchesColumn3.[KEY])
```

Here's an example if you want to preserve the original rank values, though be mindful of the added performance hit:

```
SELECT
   MatchAllColumns.[RANK],
   Case
      When (MatchesColumn1or2.[KEY] is not null) Then 'Matches Column 1 or 2'
      When (MatchesColumn3.[KEY] is not null) Then 'Matches Column 3'
   End
FROM
   FREETEXTTABLE(MyTable, *, 'cat AND dog') as MatchAllColumns
left join
   FREETEXTTABLE(MyTable, (Column1, Column2), 'cat AND dog') as MatchesColumn1or2
   on (MatchAllColumns.[KEY] = MatchesColumn1or2.[KEY])
left join
   FREETEXTTABLE(MyTable, Column3, 'cat AND dog') as MatchesColumn3
   on (MatchAllColumns.[KEY] = MatchesColumn3.[KEY])
```

Comment: Thanks. Well done. This is a very interesting answer indeed. Before closing this question I want to see if there is another option since my table is huge and already flattened, this requires another full outer join which can be very expensive.

Comment: I agree, this may be expensive. I'm interested in seeing other solutions too. However I don't believe there is any way to know the matched column when calling FREETEXTTABLE or CONTAINSTABLE as you originally asked.

Comment: Problem: Is there a way to sort by rank. If I cant sort by relenvancy, I am afraid I have nothing to do with this select results. By adding "SELECT MatchesColumn1or2.RANK,MatchesColumn3.RANK," in the begining I see two different ranks. Since in the docs it is mentioned that the rank is valid/related only for a single query of a table, I think I cant merge them

Comment: That's correct, you can't combine those results and get a consistent rank. I posted a 2nd example to help you achieve that but it may not be ideal from a performance perspective. I don't think there will be an easy solution to your answer since SQL Server doesn't intrinsically support what you're asking for. I think you'll have to either suffer a performance hit (my 2nd example), tweak my 1st example to normalize the ranks, or look into other search engine products.